# How to use variables in docker-compose as named volume for several services?

Tags: docker, variables, docker-compose, docker-volume

how can I use environment variables in named volumes? Lets say we have this:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  nginx:
    image: imagename
    volumes:
     - ${NGINX_VOLUME_NAME}:/var/lib/nginx
    ports:
     - 80:8080
  mysql:
    image: imagename
    volumes:
     - ${MYSQL_VOLUME_NAME}:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
     - 3306:3306

volumes:
  ${NGINX_VOLUME_NAME}:
  ${MYSQL_VOLUME_NAME}:
```

So I know that this unfortunately does not work. The documentation says something with `external: true` but I did not really understand this.

I would really appreciate if someone could show me with this example how to handle this :) Thanks you.

Comment: What's your goal in trying this?  Compose generally includes the _project name_ (by default the current directory name) in the names of volumes and other things, so it's okay to use a fairly generic name like `mysql-data` for the volume names here, and it won't conflict with other Compose-based things.

Comment: What's your motivation / problem to require configurable volume names? Are you referring to existing named volumes or do you want to pass some specific paths to be used?

Comment: My motivation is when I start a second container from the compose file, it should write the log files of the second container to the another volume. It works when I set the variables as paths but in production it is recommended to use named volumes.

Comment: If you set [`$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) to a different name, you will get different containers and volumes.  (If your proposed `docker-compose.yml` file worked, it would replace the old containers with new ones mounting different volumes, which doesn't sound like what you're after.)